# How to fix the position of a button for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fixed the button by declaring the `position: Fixed;` but it works for whole page. Is there any solution so the the button be fixed for a div with its `height:200px`. What I am trying to do is the button which is fixed for its parent's div height.  Any help are surely appretiated.

I have done like this

```
    <div style="Height:200px; width:45%;">
      <div style="position:fixed; top:100px; left:253px;">
             <asp:Button ID="ReplyEventButton" runat="server" Text="Reply to this Ad"  />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Button in the center of the div? Can you please provide more details? Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to fix the button not for the whole page but only for the parent div which has a height of 200px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting the button to be positioned relative to its containing div, but slightly offset?

If this is what you are asking for, then try the following:

```
<div style="height: 200px; width: 45%;">
  <div style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 253px;">
     <asp:Button ID="ReplyEventButton" runat="server" Text="Reply to this Ad"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

This offsets the element without removing it from the page flow.

If you are wanting it to be detached from the flow of the page, then follow easwee's advice of using a relative parent and absolute child.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`. Your parent div needs to have `position: relative`.

```
<div style="height:200px; width:45%; position:relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top:100px; left:253px;">
         <asp:Button ID="ReplyEventButton" runat="server" Text="Reply to this Ad"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; Height:200px; width:45%;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top:100px; left:253px;">
         <asp:Button ID="ReplyEventButton" runat="server" Text="Reply to this Ad"  />
  </div>
</div>
```